# if con.createStatement() method is present in connection interface then how it is returning statement type refrence

Tags: object, jdbc, interface, instance

```
stmt=con.createStatement();
```

kindly explain this and how we are creating instance of interfaces

kindly explain me the instance of interfaces are not possible, but how it is done then

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`createStatement()` returns an instance of a concrete class that implements the `Statement` interface.